# Google Maps JS API v3 - Post Page is Losing Map After Map Resize

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, post, google-maps-api-3, timer

i'm using this code to make my map fullscreen. **http://www.doogal.co.uk/FullScreen.php**  But in my **ASP.NET page** i've got a **timer** which is doing **postback** every 5 seconds. [**This**](http://www.doogal.co.uk/FullScreen.php) fullscreen button is working properly till this postback. When postback raises i can't show map anymore and Javascript got no error.

*Note : I'm also calling initialize method after every postback.*

**Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, when i try to initialize map on every post it's trying to create a new map object. I just moved my map variable to global and checked it like :

```
var map=null;

function initialize()
{
.
.
.
if (map == null) {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_googleMap"), mapProp);
}
else
{
.
.
.
}
}
```